# Subscribing send port request to file biztalk

Tags: request, runtime, port, biztalk, send

I would like to subscribe request message of 2-way Send Port and write it down do HDD. 
I found article, when it applied only to responses, called [HOW TO SUBSCRIBE THE RESPONSE MESSAGE OF 2-WAY (REQUEST- RESPONSE) SEND PORT)](https://prashantbiztalkblogs.wordpress.com/2015/03/08/how-to-subscribe-the-response-message-of-2-way-request-response-send-port/)

I also failed with send port group as FILE send port is Static-One-Way and second is SOAP 2-way.

Is there any trick to see at runtime what requests are going through Send port?

Comment: The best way is almost always to enable Message Tracking on the Port.  Then it all happens automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Your options are

1. Turn on Message Body Tracking on the Send Port, restart your Tracking host, and then use the BizTalk Admin Console to look at the messages.
2. Create a filter on the FILE port of the `BTS.MessageType = <namespace>#<root>` matching the message being sent to the SOAP 2-way port

The BTS.SPName mentioned in the article you linked to is useful if you want to subscribe to the response coming from the send port.

Comment: Why I don't see Send Ports names of entire application on Value List with "Tracked Message Event" -> Port Name filter applied?

Comment: @PiotrGrudzień I believe it has some smarts built in and filters it down to those that have had messages for which you have at least some tracked the events occurring.